How to make splash screen work for API Version below 33

<style name="Theme.JetpackIntroduction" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" />

<style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splash_screen_logo_animated</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">1000</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.JetpackIntroduction</item>
</style>


above is the theme.xml file and i have called the installSplashScreen() in my main activity.
The splash screen in working for api: 33 but not for below versions.
Is there any way i can fix this?
The splash screen is not visible on api version below 33

What dependency did you add?

dependencies {
implementation("androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0")
}
